# During installing express package in Node js, I got an error

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed nodejs version node-v8.12.0-x64.msi.

I am installing express using `npm install express --save` in windows but getting following error

[image: screenshot]

And also an important update only express is the package that causes problem otherwise other packages are installing properly. I also installed previous versions but still no luck.

Any suggestions would be gently appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably in your package.json or package-lock.json files. You should include de content in the **-debug.log file to further info, try to create a new folder an then use "npm init", press enter for all questions then install Express.js. If all works the problem is in those files.

Comment: Hi desoares, I tried everything to run express, including also tried different versions of node. But still problem stands. And also I create a new folder and use "npm init" and after that installed express but same problem occur. So what can I do next?

Comment: Post the content of the latest  **-debug.log for further info. The second to last line of the print screen has the path.

Comment: I cannot understood yet, What is the problem, In the logs it show same thing that I got in terminal. So what is the best possible solution?